# Python DataArray Resample to Calendar Quarters not Seasons

Tags: python, calendar, sample

I'm trying to resample a dataarray/xarray with data from 1991 to 2020 years in python to group the data into quarters by calendar year not season (i.e., Q1 = JFM, Q2 = AMJ, ... Q4 = OND). My dataarray 'wind_abs' is of dimension -

```
wind_abs.dims
Out[70]: ('time', 'latitude', 'longitude')
```

My objective is to find the "Quarter" mean of *wind_abs* for a given Q1, Q2, etc. like this resampling by time = "QS" but it does not appear to be saving the data into calendar Qs but it saves it in the season Quarters - DJF, MAM, JJA, etc.

```
result = ((wind_abs * month_length).resample(time='QS').sum() / 
          month_length.resample(time='QS').sum())
```

This groupby groups the "quarters" by DJF, MAM, etc and not JFM, AMJ, etc. This is the groupby line:

```
quarter_means =result.sel(time=slice('1991-01','2020-12')).groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time')
```

And quarter_means looks like this:

```
         3.64661711, 3.8892598 ],
        [7.11546124, 7.10872887, 7.10433542, ..., 3.14532851,
         3.58238379, 3.93932429]]])
Coordinates:
    number     int32 0
    step       timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    surface    float64 0.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 65.0 64.75 64.5 64.25 ... 0.75 0.5 0.25 0.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -140.0 -139.8 -139.5 ... -55.5 -55.25 -55.0

  * season     (season) object 'DJF' 'JJA' 'MAM' 'SON'
```

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I discovered that changing the groupby statement from "season" to "quarter" works as the solution. And, python identifies a quarter as 1,2,3,4 integers and not "JFM" or "MAM". So queries by 'quarter' and not 'season'.